# Google AdSense Managament API always returns 0 records

Tags: google-api, adsense

I'm currently working with the Google AdSense Management API to retrieve data and store it in our data warehouse.

I tried working with this on the 'Try this API'-part in the documentation in Google, but whatever I try, no records are available.

I can clearly see that there is (in fact, a lot of) data in the portal. What am I missing? The accountId is correct (took it from the portal too). Whatever metric I try to give, it's always the same response. What am I doing wrong?[image: Data from the portal.]

```
{
 "kind": "adsense#report",
 "totalMatchedRows": "0",
 "headers": [
  {
   "name": "DATE",
   "type": "DIMENSION"
  }
 ],
 "totals": [
  ""
 ],
 "averages": [
  ""
 ],
 "startDate": "2018-12-11",
 "endDate": "2018-12-15"
}
```

Comment: It seems like startDate and endDate are the only required parameters. Have you tried query just with those 2 filled out?

Comment: @fcsr Thank you for your response. Without the parameter (DATE), it returns 0 records too.